# Plot ROC curve for bootstrapped caret model

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a model like the following:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)
set.seed(998)

my_data <- Sonar

fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "boot632",
    number = 10,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = T,
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )


model <- train(
  Class ~ .,
  data = my_data,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = fitControl,
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

How do I plot the ROC curve for this model? As I understand it, the probabilities must be saved (which I did in trainControl), but because of the random sampling which bootstrapping uses to generate a 'test' set, I am not sure how caret calculates the ROC value and how to generate a curve.

To isolate the class probabilities for the best performing parameters, I am doing:

```
for (a in 1:length(model$bestTune))       
{model$pred <-
        model$pred[model$pred[, paste(colnames(model$bestTune)[a])] == model$bestTune[1, a], ]}
```

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an explanation:

If you are not going to check how each possible hyper parameter combination predicted on each sample in each re-sample you can set `savePredictions = "final"` in `trainControl` to save space:

```
fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "boot632",
    number = 10,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = "final",
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )
```

after running the model:

```
model <- train(
  Class ~ .,
  data = my_data,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = fitControl,
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

results of interest are in `model$pred`

here you can check how many samples were tested in each re-sample (I set 25 repetitions)

```
nrow(model$pred[model$pred$Resample == "Resample01",]) 
#83
```

caret always provides prediction from rows not used in the model build.

```
nrow(my_data) #208
```

83/208 makes sense for the test samples for `boot632`

Now to build the ROC curve. You may opt for several options here:

-average the probability for each sample and use that (this is usual for CV since you have all samples repeated the same number of times, but it can be done with boot also).

-plot all as is without averaging

-plot ROC for each re-sample.

I will show you the second approach:

Create a data frame of class probabilities and true outcomes:

```
for_lift = data.frame(Class = model$pred$obs,  xgbTree = model$pred$R)
```

plot ROC:

```
pROC::plot.roc(pROC::roc(response = for_lift$Class,
                         predictor = for_lift$xgbTree,
                         levels = c("M", "R")),
           lwd=1.5)
```

[image]

You can also do this with ggplot, to do so I find it easiest to make a lift object using caret function `lift`

```
lift_obj = lift(Class ~ xgbTree, data = for_lift, class = "R")
```

specify which class the probability was used ^.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(lift_obj$data)+
  geom_line(aes(1-Sp , Sn, color = liftModelVar))+
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "method"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to reduce the "Test' set for each Resample? In this example, it was about 40%, but in my actual data set which is much smaller, 40% will be too high.

Comment: It can not be reduced while using "boot632" (it uses arround 63% for train and the rest for test)  but it can if you are using "cv" for instance if you set `number = 10` and `method = cv` you will perform 10 - fold cross validation which will use 90% of the data for model building and 10% for evaluation.

Comment: I liked the random selection aspect of boot632, which is why I chose it. Is it possible to randomly assign the folds on cv each time it is resampled?

Comment: You can manually specify indexes on which training and testing will be performed in each iteration check out ?trainControl and index/IndexOut arguments

Comment: @missuse What would be the easiest way to annotate the AUC value on the ggplot2 graph? Thanks!

Comment: @Jack Arnestad: You can use [`annotate`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html). I am away from pc to show in code. Will update the post in a few days.